# I have plugin built in craft cms3, I want to use same plugin in craft cms4

Tags: plugins, craftcms

I have simply copy and paste plugin( plugin name is websitetoolbox) folder to craft cms4's vendor folder. And modify root composer.json like below.

```
{
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^4.2.0.2",
    "swishdigital/template-selector": "^1.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4.0",
    "websitetoolbox/websitetoolboxforum": "1.4.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {    
    "yiisoft/yii2-shell": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "craftcms/plugin-installer": true,
      "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "8.0.2"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

When I run command composer update it gives below **error**

**Problem 1**
- Root composer.json requires websitetoolbox/websitetoolboxforum 1.4.0, found websitetoolbox/websitetoolboxforum[dev-master, 1.0.0, 1.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
"websitetoolbox/websitetoolboxforum": "1.4.0"
```

Should probably be:

```
"websitetoolbox/websitetoolboxforum": "1.3.0"
```

I'm no expert on semantic versioning, but it seems a bit odd that you have a *higher* version number? Could it be a typo on your end? Cause if another dependency requires this version you might be in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I change to 1.3.0 it will ask me like 1.3.0 will require craft cms 3.0.0 and you are having craft cms 4.0